# Permissions for Flow Users on ContentDocuments

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions, permission-sets, contentversion, contentdocument

I have a signature capture screen flow that allows us to get digital signatures for users. When testing as a system admin everything worked as expected but **when running as a user they don't appear to have the visibility or access to the ContentDocument object** so they can't store their signature and even if the signature was available the GetRecords component returns zero results for them.

Here is a basic outline of the flow where I'm experiencing issues
[image]

And here is my query on the Get Records component. As I mentioned it works for my admin user but not for any of my users.
[image]

I've looked everywhere for an understanding of what permissions I need to adjust but nothing I've tried seems to work and I obviously don't want to provide more access than necessary. For now I've created a Permission Set and associated it to a Permission Set Group that my collection of users are associated with. Is there a specific permission I can add to the Permission Set?

Comment: How are these files created and can they see these files outside of the flow, just in the normal UI?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party Signature Capture (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q5XOEAY). From what I can tell it appears that the user didn't have access to the library, I think the "manage libraries" gave them the ability to save it and now it appears to be working (still waiting on users to respond)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem may be related to the fact that Content Documents are actually represented by three separate pieces of metadata:

Content Document represents the file in the abstract. But “real” versions of this document are distinct and have different version numbers, so there’s also a…

Content Version represents a specific version of the Content Document. A Content Document can have multiple Content Versions

Content Document Link is used to connect a Content Document to a record.

I suspect that if you grant access to all three of those, you'll get the result you want.

Check out https://unofficialsf.com/using-files-and-attachments-in-flow/ for more info.